# What is a good example of an NL-complete context free language?

Tags: complexity-theory, context-free, space-complexity

**Setting**
Exactly as the title stated:

> Give an example of an $\mathsf{NL}$-complete context free language. $\newcommand{\angle}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}$

**Current Solution**

Recall in the past we proved that $E_{DFA}$ is regular, so it is also context free. $E_{DFA}$ is in $\mathsf{NL}$ since given DFA $\mathcal M$ over $n$ states, we can start at the initial state and nondeterminstically traverse through states of $\mathcal M$ for at most $n$ steps, storing only the current state ($\log n$ space). Note if there is a path to an accept state, then it must be $\le n$ steps long. So if there is no path to an accept state within $n$ steps, then $\mathcal M$ does not accept any string, thus $\mathcal M \in E_{DFA}$.

Now we show $\overline{PATH} \le_l E_{DFA}$ and since $PATH$ is $\mathsf{NL}$-complete and $\mathsf{NL} = \mathsf{coNL}$, it follows that $E_{DFA}$ is also $\mathsf{NL}$-complete. Given an instance $\angle{G,s,t}$, we construct a DFA $\mathcal M$ by letting $s \in G$ be $q_{initial}$, and $t \in G$ be $q_{accept}$. We label the edge arbitrarily from $\{0,1\}$. Clearly this can be done in log-space. So now we show
    $$\angle{G,s,t} \in \overline{PATH} \Leftrightarrow \mathcal M \in E_{DFA}.$$

Suppose $\angle{G,s,t} \in \overline{PATH}$, then there is no path from $s$ to $t$, so there is no path from $q_{initial}$ to $q_{accept}$ in $\mathcal M$, then $\mathcal M$ does not accept any strings so it is in $E_{DFA}$. Conversely, suppose $\angle{G,s,t} \not\in E_{DFA}$, then there is a path from $s$ to $t$, taking this path in $\mathcal M$ correspond to a $\mathcal M$ accepting some string, so $\mathcal L(\mathcal M) \ne \emptyset$ and $\mathcal M \not\in E_{DFA}$.

**Problem**

I don't think my algorithm for proving $E_{DFA} \in \mathsf{NL}$ is correct.

Comment: You are not likely to get an example, perhaps [this post](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14873/is-cfl-strictly-contained-in-nl) can explain why.

Comment: would empty DFA be a candidate?

Comment: What research/self-study have you done?  Where have you looked?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research and self-study before asking and to tell us in the question what you've tried / where you've looked / what you do and don't understand.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.  I encourage you to edit your question to flesh it out a bit more.

Comment: @D.W. I provided a solution, it seems too good to be true though ...

Comment: Can you define $E_{DFA}$? I understand that it is the language of DFAs accepting the empty language, but you have to explain how these DFAs are encoded. I can't think of any reasonable encoding for which this language would be regular, or even context free.

Comment: Cross-posted on math.se: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261100/what-is-an-example-of-an-nl-complete-context-free-language

Answer (score 2):

In other words, you are asked to find an $\rm NL$-complete language $A$ and a context-free language $B$ such that $A \equiv_{\rm{L}} B$. We choose $A = \it{PATH}$ and $\{{\tt{0}, \tt{1}， \tt{\#}}\}^* \supseteq  B = f(A)$, in which $f: A \to B$ is defined as follows.
    $$
\newcommand{\Bra}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}
  f(\Bra{G, s, t}) = \Bra{s}^{\mathcal{R}}({\tt{\#}} \Bra{e_1} \Bra{e_2} \cdots \Bra{e_m} {\tt{\#}} )^n\Bra{t},
 $$
    where $G = (V, E)$, $|V| = n$, $E = \{e_1, \dots, e_m\}$, $\Bra{e_i} = {\tt{\#}}\Bra{u_i}{\tt{\#}}\Bra{v_i}^{\mathcal{R}{}}{\tt{\#}}$ if $e_i = (u_i, v_i)$.